# Get access to UI events loop in Android

Tags: android, events, user-interface, filter

is there any way to analyze all the UI events occuring in an Android UI.
For example, installing an event filter in the main UI event loop, as done in other classical windowing systems.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler mHandler =  Handler(); //get UI Handler
Looper mLooper = mHandler.getLooper(); //get UI Looper
```

as per [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#getLooper%28%29) the default Handler in a Activity is the UI Thread.  Beyond that though if you want access to the event lists you will have to add a specific listener for the specific event type.

e.g. 
OnDraw(Canvas canvas) for draw events.
OnClickListeners etc.
OnTouchListeners etc.

Comment: hi!! thanks for the comment, but I would like to install something like a general filter, and not to have to register a set of listener methods for every View element